# Heap & Stack Usage ARM Cortex M3, M5

Tags: memory, arm, profiling, cortex-m, heap-profiling

I want to measure Stack and heap usage while certain mathematical algorithm is running on my Renesas S3A7 ARM M3 based controller.
Is there any way or procedure how I can measure the maximum memory utilized while executing certain functionality?

Comment: why would you have heap on a microcontroller?  sounds like a broken design.  For stack usage, you can use a valgrind like approach

Comment: your compiler might provide a setting to check or log the deepest the stack has reached.  if you are using a heap you can go into your malloc/sbrk code and add something to track the furthest into memory you have allocated.

Comment: what is a cortex-m5?

Comment: Thanks old_timer for your reply. I am using ARM Cortex M3.

Comment: I mean to say M7. Did typo saying M3.

Answer (score 0):

To measure the stack or heap usage you have to initialize this area with a padding value before usage, you can choose one listed below

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak

For example:
  0xBAADF00D or 0xDEADBEEF.

The idea is to count the number of padding value left to estimate the maximum usage.